# App Thinning Size Report reports totally different size then App Store size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, app-thinning

I have a big iPad app that has an iPhone & Watch "remote" app, ie. a little app that runs on the iPhone/Watch to remote-control the ipad. All of this is together in a universal app. For app thinning I've separated assets in the assets catalog as required. **The app is already on the App Store (released).**  The app has a minimum SDK version of iOS 8.1.

When I take the Archive that was released on the App Store, do an adhoc export, choose to build from bitcode, and choose to export for iPhone 6S, then the `App Thinning Size Report.txt` shows "19MB compressed, 39.4MB uncompressed". 19MB would be acceptable to me, considering there's 2 * swift dylibs in there (watch appex, and main app)

**BUT**: On the app-store when viewed on an iPhone 6S with iOS 9.3.4, the app size shows as a massive 42MB download! I assume this is compressed, so why is this more than twice as big as the 19MB that I was expecting? Is it because the app supports iOS 8.1, and therefore no app thinning ever happens even for devices that have iOS 9?

I want to release an update to fix this but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Ignore the compressed size, the uncompressed size is accurate. It says 39.4MB and on the actual store it was 42MB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I burned one of my 2 yearly Apple TIs for this. 
Turns out that what you see when you're on the App Store, looking at an app's size, is it's *uncompressed/installed* size. Not its download-size.

Also, on itunes connect it turns out you can click on the build (or go Activity -> All Builds -> (choose build) Build Details), and then there's a link there called *App Store File Sizes*. When you click THAT, you get much much more detail - ie. both sizes for each device type.

So, everything is awesome. Everything is cool when you're part of a team.

Comment: Everything is awesome when you're living out a dream

Comment: Like I was saying above in case you missed it, ignore the compressed size, the uncompressed size is accurate. It says 39.4MB and on the actual store it was 42MB.